# Express a number as sum of consecutive numbers (not number of ways it can be expressed)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

I am trying to understand the question -:

Given a number N, write a function to express N as sum of two or more consecutive positive numbers. If there is no solution, output -1. If there are multiple solution, then print one of them.

Examples:

Input : N = 10
Output : 4 + 3 + 2 + 1

Input  : N = 8
Output : -1

Input  : N = 24
Output : 9 + 8 + 7

[Link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-number-sum-consecutive-numbers/)

Here I got the explanation.

```
Sum of first n natural numbers = n * (n + 1)/2

Sum of first (n + k) numbers = (n + k) * (n + k + 1)/2

If N is sum of k consecutive numbers, then
following must be true.

N = [(n+k)(n+k+1) - n(n+1)] / 2

OR 

2 * N = [(n+k)(n+k+1) - n(n+1)]
```

But the problem arises in the code.

```
static void findConsecutive(int N)
{
    for (int last=1; last<N; last++)
    {
        for (int first=0; first<last; first++)
        {
            if (2*N == (last-first)*(last+first+1))
            {
                System.out.printf(N + " = ");
                printConsecutive(last, first+1);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("-1");
}
```

I am not able to get why it is using

> 2*N == (last - first) * (last + first + 1);

Please help.

Comment: If $N$ has an odd prime factor $p$ it can be expressed as the same of $p$ consecutive integers. Otherwise it is a power of $2$. The integers in the first case need not be positive, though.

Comment: @MarkBennet So what is the relationship between 2*N == (last - first) * (last + first + 1); and your comment? I have the idea of calculating the number of ways.

Comment: Actually if $first$ is the first of the consecutive integers and $last$ the last, it should be $$\sum_{j=first}^{last} j = last(last+1)/2 - (first-1)(first)/2 = (last+first)(last+1-first)/2$$

Comment: I also thought so. So there it is given wrong.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Please rewrite your comment as answer as this is the valid solution and explanation of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As requested, turning the comment into an answer)

Actually if $first$ is the first of the consecutive integers and $last$ the last, it should be
$$
\sum_{j=first}^{last} j = last(last+1)/2 - (first-1)(first)/2 = (last+first)(last+1-first)/2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$(n+k)(n+k+1) - n(n+1)=2nk+k^2+k=(2n+k+1)k=\\
((\underbrace{n+k}_{last})+(\underbrace{n+1}_{first}))((\underbrace{n+k}_{last})-(\underbrace{n+1}_{first})+1).\\
$$